# I want to get two tables data then get the percentage amount

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Here is my code,

```
$query= $this->db->select('tbl_donated.*,tbl_donation_post.*,tbl_users.*,SUM(tbl_donated.dd_amount) AS dd_amount,SUM(tbl_donated.dd_amount_se) AS dd_amount_se')
                ->from('tbl_donated,tbl_users') 
                ->join('tbl_donation_post','tbl_donation_post.d_id = tbl_donated.d_id','left')
                ->where('tbl_donation_post.d_status',1)
                ->where('tbl_donated.dd_status',1)

                ->where('tbl_donation_post.d_created_by = tbl_users.user_id')
                ->group_by('tbl_donation_post.d_id')
                ->get();

        $data = $query->result_array();

$arr = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($data as $field){
             $percent = round((($field['ddd_amount']+$field['ddd_amount_se'])/$field['d_amount'])*100);
             '<br>';
            if($percent >= 100){
                $arr[$i] = $field;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $arr;
```

I want to get the percentage amount from two tables but the code says database error. I can't find the error.
I show all the model code in the above.

Comment: what is '<br>'; before if($percentage >= 100)? echo '<br>': ??

Comment: oh sorry its line break code if i check with print_r function. it will be remove. its not mandotory.

Answer (score 1):

i think

```
 $percent = round((($field['ddd_amount']+$field['ddd_amount_se'])/$field['d_amount'])*100);
```

should be

```
 $percent = round((($field['dd_amount']+$field['dd_amount_se'])/$field['dd_amount'])*100);
```

ddd_amount, ddd_amount_se, d_amount

should be

dd_amount, dd_amount_se, dd_amount

Comment: `/$field['d_amount'])*100);` 
this field `d_amount` totally from another table . but i change others that works for me. Thanks for fixing a silly mistake.